# MongoDb query in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

In feed collection  "likeCount" and "commentCount" are  two column and I want to sum these two column and show only top 5 records. For that I have written the below query in MongoDb.

How can I write the same thing in Spring ?

```
 db.feed.aggregate(
   [
 { $project: { _id: 1, popularityCount: { $add: [ "$likeCount", "$commentCount" ] } } },
 { "$sort": { "popularityCount": -1 } },
     {"$limit":5}

  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Data Mongo and check out the [aggregation support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

```
@Autowired private MongoTemplate mongo;

public List<TopFeed> findTopFeeds() {
    // { $project: { _id: 1, popularityCount: { $add: [ $likeCount, $commentCount ] } } }
    final ProjectionOperation projection = project("_id").and("likeCount").plus("commentCount").as("popularityCount");

    // { $sort: { popularityCount: -1 } }
    final SortOperation sort = sort(DESC, "popularityCount");

    // { $limit: 5 }
    final LimitOperation limit = limit(5);

    // run against collection "feed" and return as a "TopFeed" object
    final AggregationResults results = mongo.aggregate(newAggregation(projection, sort, limit), "feed", TopFeed.class);

    // get the results
    return results.getMappedResults();
}

public class TopFeed {
    private String id;
    private long popularityCount;
}
```

If you don't want to use Spring Data you'll have to hit the Mongo client itself.  Just inject a `com.mongodb.Mongo` or `com.mongodb.MongoClient` with Spring and use it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Everything is working fine only it cannot sort the result in descending order.  I am using "Sort.Direction.DESC" in place of "DESC" because it gives error as DESC cannot be resolved to a variable. When I print the aggregation query it shows      { "$project" : { "_id" : 1 , "popularityCount" : { "$add" : [ "$likeCount" , "$commentCount"]}}} , { "$sort" : { "likeCount" : -1}} , { "$limit" : 5}

Comment: Thanks kab for your help. When I am using query as you suggested then it sort by "likeCount" not by "popularityCount".....